# Changing my iTunes account details

Tags: apple-id, itunes-store

I have a UK account but have relocated to Australia.
I'm trying desperately to change my account details but the system won't let me as I have £10 credit on my UK account.

I don't mind losing the £10 I just want to change my details to my new Oz details.

Anyone know how?
Also, is possible to credit the £10 to my Oz account as that would be fantastic.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what happens when you try to switch?

Comment: it says 'you have a store credit balance, you must spend your balance before you can change stores'. Also fyi the UK card on my account has now expired..

Comment: For this, I would actually contact Apple at the following: http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/ They'll be more than happy to work through your issue and will be able to provide a real solution that I'm afraid people here won't (like transferring the funds, etc.).

Comment: If you live close to a store best is to go there and they will help you out for sure.
-- I'm wondering what the results were btw..

Answer (score 1):

After searching around the internet, it sounds like other people are having this same issue. You could try [contacting Apple](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/) to get their advice, but it will probably be easier to just spend the £10 credit on something and then try switching again.

Comment: thanks guys, 
i cant even spend the £10 as my card has now expired..

Comment: Are you sure you can't purchase something under £10 without a card? That's unfortunate... definitely try to get in touch with Apple! At the worst, you could create a new account to use in the Australian store.

Comment: no i cant even purchase under £10 as my card has now expired. is there actually a way of contacting Apple directly?? it seems the apple support pages dont allow it

Comment: If you go through the Express Lane option (http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/), you should be able to send them an email.

Comment: There used to be an option where you didn't have to select a payment method. Maybe that's still available?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the credit card from your account first. Then you can spend the £10.

1. Launch iTunes, go to iTunes store.
2. Click the "down arrow" next to your email at the top right side of the page and click "Account."
3. Enter your username and password and click "View Account" to log into your account information.
4. Next to your Payment Type, click "Edit."
5. Select the "None" button and click "Done."

You can confirm your card has been removed by going back to the Apple account info screen and under payment type, it should say that there is no payment information on record.

This will make your account work as if it was started with an iTunes gift card.

From there you should be able to switch over the the aussie store.

Answer (score -1):

Not true.  The device will still tell you:
"you have a store credit balance; you must spend your balance before you can change stores.".

Terrible catch-22 situation that Apple has put their global users in.
I have an amount of $4cents left on my iPhone, but moved to Europe.
I have no way of spending this amount, so I can start using local European iTune cards.
Completely crazy situation!!

Comment: That stinks. You might need someone to set up an allowance or gift for just the proper amount to make a purchase. I can't believe if you contacted the store support team, they wouldn't send a refund or offer some way to clear that balance to your and Apple's mutual satisfaction.

Comment: What happened to your 4 cent balance? Did you eventually find a nice game for 99 cents and buy it? Were you abel to reach Apple Support?